# Number of connected sets intersecting a given set in $\mathbb{Z}^d$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}^d$ and let $|A|$ be its cardinality. Let $F_n(A)$ be the number of connected sets of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ having cardinality $n$ and intersecting $A$ in at least one site. Assume we know the function $F_n(0)$, where $0$ is the set containing only the origin.

For a connected set $A$, is there a qualitatively better upper bound than $$F_n(A) \leq |A| \cdot F_n(0),$$ which holds for $n$ large, $|A|$ large?

**Comment** In my opinion, $F_n(A)$ should be much smaller, as for each site of $A$, most of the ``large'' connected sets intersecting such a site will intersect the other sites of $A$ as well. Hence they should not be counted $|A|$ times.

Comment: A very interesting (and probably very hard) question. However I do not understand, why do you write this $\setminus A$? How can a set intersect $A$ if it is in $\mathbb{Z}^d \setminus A$?

Comment: There was a typo... I modified it.